# html select option into a list

Tags: python, html, text-processing

Is there any way I could select all the `<option>s` in the following HTML form `<select>` into a python list, like so, ['a','b','c','d']?

```
<select name="sel">
   <option value="a">a</option>
   <option value="b">b</option>
   <option value="c">c</option>
   <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re
text = '''<select name="sel">
   <option value="a">a</option>
   <option value="b">b</option>
   <option value="c">c</option>
   <option value="d">d</option>
</select>'''
pattern = re.compile(r'<option value="(?P<val>.*?)">(?P=val)</option>')
handy_list = pattern.findall(text)
print handy_list
```

will output

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

**Disclaimer:** Parsing HTML with regular expressions does not work in the general case.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at BeautifulSoup if you want to parse other HTML data also

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

text = '''<select name="sel">
   <option value="a">a</option>
   <option value="b">b</option>
   <option value="c">c</option>
   <option value="d">d</option>
</select>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

print [i.string for i in soup.findAll('option')]
```